# Multiple selection in Word: find in code

Tags: c#, ms-word, automation

In an opened word document, by pressing Ctrl I can select multiple words in different paragraphs, separated by unselected words.

How can I find multiple blocks of text that are not contiguous, in the code?

Just using document.Selection returns the last selected word, 
and others are left behind but still visually selected.

For example, an ArrayList below will contain 1 element in the list.

```
ArrayList paras = new ArrayList();
foreach (Paragraph para in _application.Selection.Paragraphs)
{
   paras.Add(para.Range.Text);
}
```

Comment: Use `thisDocument.Selection` ? Or write a better question

Comment: Won't work. This just returns the last selected word.

Comment: Cleaned up the text slightly...I think your added text about how the seemingly obvious solution (document.Selection) doesn't work will also help.

Comment: _application.Selection returns last selection and hence _application.Selection.Paragraphs returns one paragraph, the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have found so far is not collecting paragraphs from every selection 
but handle **WindowSelectionChange** event and add a paragraph in collection which I can process later after a user has finished making selection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.applicationevents4_windowselectionchangeeventhandler%28v=office.11%29.aspx